# how do i find larger primes with this code i dont have any errors with higher nubers just a straight up site crash

Tags: javascript

```js
  var talet = 20;
var primtal = true;

var test = 2;
while (test < talet)
{
    if (talet % test == 0) { primtal = false; }
    test += 1;
}

if (talet == 1)
  alert("false")
  else alert(primtal)
```

much hof this is written in swedish talet = the number ptimtal = prime number

Comment: Could you provide a non working code sample please

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve time complexity is to test for potential divisors only until the square_root of your target number.

So step 1 for improvement:

```
const sqrt = Math.sqrt(talet);
const test = 2;
while(test < sqrt){
    if(talet % test == 0){
        primtal = false;
        break; //will jump out of the loop
    }
}
```

Now, improving your code further depends on what you need to do. Do you need to compute the primality of only one number or many numbers?

If you need to compute only one number, then this method is correct to use. If you need to compute the primality of many numbers, then you might want to compute an array of prime numbers. And test only for divisors in that array.

Comment: "If you need to compute only one number, then this method is correct." - this method is correct either way, it just gets inefficient with larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is too inefficient to check larger primes for primality as it runs in linear time O(n), checking divisors up to the number. For a binary number with k digits, this is yields a worst-case runtime exponential in k of O(2^k), which is pretty poor and becomes unbearably slow even for rather "small" number such as `1e12`.

If you need all primes in a range, take a look at the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://the-algorithms.com/de/algorithm/sieve-of-eratosthenes?lang=javascript).

If you only want to check selected large numbers for primality, you might want to look into the probabilistic [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). You can then generate large primes by generating large random numbers and checking them using the Miller-Rabin test.

Your simple sieve can be optimized by only checking divisors up to the square root of the number; you can also exit the loop as soon as you've found a divisor:

```js
var talet = 10000;
var primtal = true;
for (let divisor = 2; divisor <= Math.sqrt(talet); divisor++)
{
    if (talet % divisor == 0) { primtal = false; break; }
}

if (talet == 1) primtal = false

alert(primtal)
```

This improves the asymptotic runtime to O(sqrt n), or in terms of k O(sqrt 2^k) = O(2^k^0.5) = O(2^(0.5k)).

Answer (score 0):

Two optimizations can be done here

1. just check numbers from 2 to square root of original number
2. just check 2 and odd numbers, for more improvement you can check numbers only in form of `6k + 1` and `6k - 1`.

```js
function isPrime(number) {

    if(number === 1 || number % 2 === 0)
        return false;
    for(let i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i += 2) {
        if(number % i === 0) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: This algorithm is incorrect. It will fail if `number` is a clean square `x*x` where `x` is odd (try `isPrime(5*5)`, it will be `true`). You need to add a check `Math.sqrt(number) % 1 === 0` or the like.